# Get the implicit lang attribute of an HTML element

Tags: javascript, iso, lang

Suppose you have an HTML page that contains sections in different languages, like this:

```
<html lang=en>
<div lang="th">
  <p id="test1">ไทย</p>
</div>
<p id="test2">Implicitly English</p>
<div lang="en-CA">
  <p id="test3">As Canadian as possible under the circumstances</p>
</div>
<p lang="en-AU"id="test4">Explictly Aussie</p>
</html>
```

Is there a direct way to discover which particular language code applies to a given HTML element? Something like:

```
// pseudo-code
var lang = myElement.getLang()
```

Here's what appears to be a very roundabout solution:

```
function getLang(element) {
  var lang = element.getAttribute("lang")

  if (!lang) {
    var elements
      , languages
      , language
      , ii
      , selector

    // Find all elements with an explicit lang attribute
    elements = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("*[lang]"))

    // Determine which languages are present
    languages = []
    for (ii in elements) {
      lang = elements[ii].getAttribute("lang")
      if (languages.indexOf(lang) < 0) {
        languages.push(lang)
      }
    }

    lang = "" // reset

    for (ii in languages) {
      language = languages[ii]
      selector = ":lang(" + language + ")"
      elements = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector))

      if (elements.indexOf(element) > -1) {
        if (lang.length < language.length) {
          lang = language
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return lang
}
```

Is there a more obvious way?
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxtjwhjz/)

Comment: `element.lang` will get you the `lang` attribute value, seems pretty direct. Or do you mean get a parents lang if the child element doesnt have one?

Comment: You can use a selector (as you have) to get the element's with lang attributes. For any particular node, you can use the [*contains*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) method to see if it's a descendant of any particular node. Your code seems convoluted, it can be simplified hugely. Note that `[].slice.call(hostObject)` will fail in IE 8.

Comment: In the latest Chrome and Firefox that entire function would be just `element.closest('[lang]').lang`

Answer (score 1):

I updated your fiddle with the following code, which you can run in this snippet. This simplifies it greatly.

```js
function getLang(elem) {
  var lang = "";
  if (elem) {
    var elements = [];
    var queryResult = document.querySelectorAll("[lang]");
    try {
      //Wrapping in a try catch block to handle unsupported browsers.
      elements = [].slice.call(queryResult);
    } catch (error) {
      for (var i = 0, len = queryResult.length; i < len; i++) {
        elements.push(queryResult[i]);
      }
    }
    if (elements.length > 0) {
      //Find in the NodeList where the element is either itself or the first parent with lang attribute of the given element.
      var matches = elements.filter(function(e) {
        return e === elem || e.contains(elem);
      }); //ES2015 -> elements.filter(e => e === elem || e.contains(elem));
      var match = matches.length > 0 ? matches[matches.length - 1] : matches[0];
      lang = match.lang ? match.lang : lang;
    }
  }
  return lang;
}

var result = getLang(document.querySelector("#test1")) + " ";
result += getLang(document.querySelector("#test2")) + " ";
result += getLang(document.querySelector("#test3")) + " ";
result += getLang(document.querySelector("#test4"));

alert(result);
```

```html
<body lang=en>
  <div lang="th">
    <p id="test1">ไทย</p>
  </div>
  <p id="test2">Implicitly English</p>
  <div lang="en-CA">
    <p id="test3">As Canadian as possible under the circumstances</p>
  </div>
  <p lang="en-AU" id="test4">Explictly Aussie</p>
</body>
```

Comment: It would be more efficient to use an IIFE to generate *elements* and keep a reference in a closure so you don't have to create it every time. However, updates to the DOM might complicate that.

Comment: @RobG it would essentially be a Singleton of the elements array that, as you stated, would not reflect updates to the DOM. Beneficial, certainly, but perhaps a bit too complicated for this use case.

Comment: it might be obvious, but why not just `document.querySelector('[lang]').attributes.lang.value` and push the value into an array?